# How to import external issues only on SonarCloud

Tags: swift, sonarqube, swiftlint, sonarcloud, sonarscanner

I'm importing swiftLint issues to Sonar using this `sonar.swift.swiftLint.reportPaths=swiftlint.json`.
This doesn't stop Sonar from analysing swift files using SonarSwift. Thus, issues from both the tools get uploaded to SonarCloud. I want Sonar to stop analysing by SonarSwift and only import SonarLint issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an empty quality profile for Swift, and select that as the active quality profile for your project. Then, I believe the `swiftLint` issues will be imported, but you will no longer see issues from SonarSwift.